# Wedderburn decomposition of wreath product of cyclic p-groups

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, p-groups, group-algebras

Let $G$ be wreath product of cyclic group of prime order $p$ by itself, i.e. $G=C_p \wr C_p$, where the action of $C_p$ is taken as cyclic permutation on generators of first $p$ cyclic groups. Can we determine wedderburn decomposition of $F_q(C_p \wr C_p)$? (where $F_q$ is field containing $q$ elements such that gcd$(p,q)=1$)

Comment: This should be easier when p divides q-1 since otherwise Fq doesnt split Cp

Comment: Isn't this the same as finding the irreducible representations of $C_p \wr C_p$ (over $\mathbb F_q$)? One can do this by finding first the irreducible representations of $C_p^{C_p}$ and then seeing how they split and merge in the wreath product.

Comment: @WillSawin, I think you need the dimensions and the endomorphism rings since Fq won’t be a splitting field in general. The endomorphism ring will be a field but I guess you need the dimension.

Comment: Alternatively since all schur índices are 1 I guess you can look at irreducibles over the algebraic closure and use Galois orbits

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Please provide some reference where schur indices are evaluated explicitly and also to study galois orbits.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Well, I would consider "finding" a representation to include finding its dimension, and usually also its endomorphism ring.

Comment: @WillSawin, fair enough.  Usually people would include dimension but not computing the endomorphism ring

Comment: Curtis and Reiner talk about Schur índices and Galois conjugates

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Since I have an irreducible representation of dimension $p$, I can say that one of the factor will be like $M_{p \times p}(F_{q^x})$. BUt how to compute $x$ ?

Comment: The degree of the matrix algebra is smaller than the dimension of the representation of the endomorphism algebra is not the ground field

Comment: Besides computing the representation and then it's endomorphism ring I'm not sure how to get $x$.